# WPF binding path in styling based on parent type

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm trying to set up automation id's on all elements of type ComboBoxItem inside Style element. I'm using Binding Path as a source for automation id property.
The problem is that the Path value should be different depends on the parent of ComboBoxItem. Sometimes it's regular ComboBox and sometimes it's our own custom ComboBox. In the former case the Path value is Content and in the latter case the Path value is Text.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
          <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId">
       <Setter.Value>
          <Binding Path="Text" /> or <Binding Path="Content"
       </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

How to set up that condition in XAML?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some code would be nice. I know you are trying to explain it all but we are not working with you so we need clear explanation of what you are trying to do and and what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [PriorityBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId">
            <Setter.Value>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Text" />
                    <Binding Path="Content" />
                </PriorityBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: It seems that it is something I was looking for. Thanks